how to know to what measure correspond itemids in labevents table in mimic3?
I am new in dealing with mimic data and I am stuck. the physiological variables I am searching for can be found in D_ITEMS and LABEVENTS tables under different itemids. the itemids are not the same in both tables.
There is no description in the labevents table, only the itemids that corresponds to certain physiological measures but it is not possible to know which one is which. In other words, how can I know what itemids corresponds to a given measure ?
I cannot found any information about that that says it explicitly. can you provide me a resource ?
PS : in my case, for example, I am searching for pao2, fio2, spo2 and things like that

[tar -xzvf apps-ubuntu-rootfs.tar.gz -C ubuntu_rootfs][1]
[1]: https://tar -xzvf apps-ubuntu-rootfs.tar.gz -C ubuntu_rootfs
